# rails 4 create new model object from association

Tags: object, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, model-associations

i'm using rails 4 and i'm trying to create a new model object with association here are my db file

```
class CreateClients < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :clients do |t|
      t.string :nume
      t.string :nrtel
      t.string :email
      t.string :datan
      t.string :var
      t.string :var1
      t.string :var2
      t.string :var3
      t.string :var4
      t.string :var5

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
class CreateProgs < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :progs do |t|
      t.string :data
      t.string :descriere
      t.string :status
      t.string :var
      t.string :var1
      t.string :var2
      t.string :var3
      t.string :var4
      t.string :var5


      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
class AddClientidToProgs < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :progs, :clientid, :integer
  end
end
```

and in the progs controller the new method looks like this

```
def new
    #@client = Client.find(params[:client_id])
    c = Client.new
    @prog = c.progs.build

  end
```

and i get this error :

unknown attribute: client_id

Extracted source (around line #19):
17
18
19
20
21
22

```
#@client = Client.find(params[:client_id])
c = Client.new
@prog = c.progs.build
```

end

Rails.root: /home/salon

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/progs_controller.rb:19:in `new'
Request

Parameters:

```
{"client_id"=>"1"}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction ?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly should set a association between `client` and `progs`.

```
class AddClientidToProgs < ActiveRecord::Migration 
   def change add_column :progs, :client_id, :integer 
   end 
end
```

You've written wrong "clientid".

2 thing is that association should be like

```
client class
    has_many :progs

prog class
   belongs_to client
```

Then finally:

```
@client = Client.find(params[:client_id])
prog = @client.progs.build # or @client.progs.new
```

Above command will set `client_id` in `prog` object.